# Can't mount partition after change lable using minitool in windows 11

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fsck

I have dual boot windows and ubuntu while working on windows I changed the partition name in minitool wizard accidentally since the partition was not showing in the drive menu I tried.

When I tried to open the partition from the ubuntu its not mounting.

error:

```
mount: /media/External: cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem on /dev/nvme0n1p5.
```

I tried to check and fix in **gparted** its shows:

```
Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/nvme0n1p5  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
        
calibrate /dev/nvme0n1p5  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/nvme0n1p5 (partition)
start: 414277632
end: 877168639
size: 462891008 (220.72 GiB)
check file system on /dev/nvme0n1p5 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
        
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/nvme0n1p5'  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
        
ext2fs_open2: Superblock checksum does not match superblock
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem. If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
or
e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
e2fsck: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1p5
```

I googled it bit and tried to restore superblock something.
following this thread https://www.linode.com/community/questions/20599/how-do-i-fix-a-bad-magic-number-in-super-block-error

```
/> mke2fs -n /dev/nvme0n1p5

mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/nvme0n1p5 contains a ext4 file system
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Creating filesystem with 57861376 4k blocks and 14467072 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 304418cd-5126-4802-96bd-09773bcdc19f
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

When run

```
sudo fsck -b 32768 /dev/nvme0n15                      1 ↵  
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/nvme0n15
Possibly non-existent device?
```

Please help my working projects are inside the partition.

Comment: Which filesystem? please.

Comment: its ext4 @nobody

Comment: Do you have some tool in windows to have access to this filesystem?

Comment: @nobody i updated question with more logs.

Comment: @nobody i can't that why i tried minitool to check it.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to try testdisk/photorec. You destroyed the metadata of the filesystem.  Here a little bit wiki https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums  I have no other idea; but maybe someone other has. I'm sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I gues something with checksum information is changed. Any way thanks for the help @nobody Ill try...

Comment: @nobody i can able to access via DiskInternals software from windows.